# Can I access a variable defined inside a jade template?

Tags: pug

I'm using jade to create email templates, so I have a jade file for each type of email and each language. I'd like to be able to set the email subject from inside the jade template, it could either be by reading a variable defined inside the template or by finding the contents of the title tag but I can't do any one of those. Is there a way to tie an html tag to a function so I can get its content? Or just be able to access a variable defined in the jade template?

Thanks!

Comment: if is only one  variable you could put it inside the name of the template. i.e. template_en.jade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've done.

First, I've extended jade.Compiler to create my own compiler rewriting the visitTag method to be able to catch when the title tag is used.

```
subjects = {}

EmailCompiler = (node, options) ->
  jade.Compiler.call(this, node, options)
EmailCompiler::__proto__ = jade.Compiler.prototype;

EmailCompiler::visitTag = (tag) ->
  if tag.name is 'title'
    subjects[@options.filename] = @getText tag.block.nodes[0]
  jade.Compiler.prototype.visitTag.call(this, tag)

EmailCompiler::getText = (nodes, glue='') ->
  [].map.call(nodes.nodes, (node) -> node.val).join glue
```

And then the jade compiler is called like this:

```
fs.readFile filePath, (err, str) ->
  jade.compile str,
    compiler: EmailCompiler
    filename: filePath
```

Hope it helps somebody!